# How to create a pie chart in Google Data Studio from aggregate date-values in Sheets?

Tags: charts, google-sheets, looker-studio

I am a little new to supermetrics, sheets and data studio so please forgive the newbie question. I am trying to show a pie chart in data studio based on the total users vs new users in a given date range.

When I get Google Analytics data into sheets (via supermetrics) it naturally comes in as 3 columns: date, users, new users.

[image]

In Google Data Studio, the pie chart wants to see a data source of 1 dimension and 1 metric: user type, user count like this:

[image]

Of course I can use formulas to calculate totals and create the secondary table, but that won't update when the GDS user changes the date range.

I also tried this which didn't work to make a pie chart:

[image]

Either I need to find a way to artificially create this 1x1 table in GDS or trigger a function in Sheets when a user changes a date range in GDS.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I just created a function in Sheets to recreate the data table in the way I need. Then i set up a trigger for that function to run whenever the source data changes.
The source data is this:

[image]

The function is this:

```
  function reformatUsersForPieChart() {
    var sheet = getSheetReference('data-ga-top-level-new-v-users-ALT'); // this is the analytics from google
    var target_sheet = getSheetReference('data-ga-top-level-new-v-users-FINAL');

    var ypos = 2,
        newdata = [];

    // clear out the target sheet
    var start = 1, end;
    end = target_sheet.getLastRow(); 
    //blank rows after last row with content will not be deleted
    if (end > start) target_sheet.clear(); //deleteRows(start, end);

    // create header row
    newdata.push(["Date", "Type of User", "Uaer Count"]);

    while (sheet.getRange(ypos, 1).getValue() != "") {
        newdata.push([sheet.getRange(ypos, 1).getValue(), "Users", sheet.getRange(ypos, 2).getValue()])
        newdata.push([sheet.getRange(ypos, 1).getValue(), "New Users", sheet.getRange(ypos, 3).getValue()])

        ypos++;
    }

    target_sheet.getRange(1, 1, newdata.length, newdata[0].length).setValues(newdata);
}
```

and the resultant table is this:

[image]